# error in update command in 20.04.4

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

```
$ apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://gplnxapp01.nebraskamed.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gplnxapp01.nebraskamed.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://gplnxapp01.nebraskamed.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://gplnxapp01.nebraskamed.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:5 http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 52.218.152.130 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 52.218.152.130 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: whatever network you're on is probably blocking access to archive.lambdalabs and the main Ubuntu archives it would seem.  Especially since it gives access to nebraskamed items but not the others.  Contact the IT team that manages the network you're on.

Comment: As a workaround, try changing the mirrors in Software Sources, and check if that works.

Comment: can you explain, how to do that

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to be more clear. For example, "apt update failing to connect in 20.04.04"